# $Max(X,Y)$ random variable with different domain

Tags: probability, random-variables

**Question:** Suppose that random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[1,2]$ and $Y$ has the following density function:

$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} \cfrac{2y}9: & 0 \le y \le 3 \\ 0: & \mathrm{elsewhere} \end{cases}$

Find the distribution function $F(t)$ of the random variable $T=\max(X,Y).$

**Attempt:**

$F_X(x) = \begin{cases} x-1: & 1<x<2 \\ 0: & \mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$

$F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} \cfrac{y^2}9: & 0<y<3 \\ 0: & \mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$

I know that $T=\max(X,Y) \implies F_T(t)=F_X(t)\cdot F_Y(t)$, but domain of first distribution function is different from domain second distribution function. Thus, if I multiply them directly, result is nonsense (e.g. not monotonic increasing function). In this case what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite $F_X$ as $$F_X(x) = (x-1) \mathbf{1}_{(1,2)}(x) + \mathbf{1}_{[2,\infty)}(x)\tag{$x\in\mathbb{R}$}$$
and $F_Y$ as
$$F_Y(x) = \frac{x^2}{9} \mathbf{1}_{(0,3)}(x) + \mathbf{1}_{[3,\infty)}\tag{$x\in\mathbb{R}$}$$
to see how they are both defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Then you can multiply them and simplify the expression, using that $\mathbf{1}_A\cdot \mathbf{1}_B = \mathbf{1}_{A\cap B}$.

---

Here is an illustration (plot made in Mathematica):
[image]

Comment: I am grateful for your answer, I kinda understood it. But I am not familiar with this notation (bold 1), what does it called? I want to search it

Comment: @EnesErdogan this is the notation for the *indicator function* of a set.